# VueJS and Vutify uses some classes which I cant find

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, stylus

New to VueJS. I have some old VueJS application and we are upgrading it to use Vue3. There is use of Vutify and Stylus for CSS in old code. I didnt install stylus in the latest code. There are some classes like `blue--text` and `black--text`, which I am not able to see anywhere defined in old code.

How those classes were defined? When I add those class in new code, I cant see the effect or that class is loaded in `inspect` element.

If this classes are coming from `stylus` package, where I can see the definition of those classes?

```
.blue {
    background-color: #2196f3 !important;
    border-color: #2196f3 !important;
}
```

This I copy from `inspect element`. But in code, its not defined anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These classes were defined for Vuetify v2. See https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/colors/

However, those class names were changed for Vuetify v3. They are now `text-blue` and `text-black`. See https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/colors/#classes